Present Continuous: Is there an oughting to, shoulding, or musting?
I just tried to say "I detest my bed oughting to stay clean" before my brain short-circuited.

Naturally the structure of the sentence works if "ought to" is replaced by other verbs:

I detest my bed having to stay clean.
I detest my bed needing to stay clean.

Yet using the verbs "ought to", "should", or "must" in present continuous sounds wrong. Is it?

The answer is of course that all modal verbs in English are defective: they lack infinitives, participles, gerunds, and -s third-person singular inflections. See the linked duplicate for more details about this.
